# Unable to unlink webp image in nodejs. Having error resource busy or locked

Tags: node.js, fs, sharpjs

**I am making img converter (png,webp,jpg,etc)**

- using multer to uplaod image and sharp to convert img
- very thing is going fine but when I unlink uploaded webp img an error shows up!

**ERROR**
`Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'public\uploads\Windows 101632682048612-.webp' at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:1251:3) at Object.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\webp\index.js:81:14) { errno: -4082, syscall: 'unlink', code: 'EBUSY', path: 'public\\uploads\\Windows 101632682048612-.webp' }`

````
  let outputFilePath =  "public/converted/"+file.originalname.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.') + "--converted." + format;
   let path=  sharp(file.path)
    .toFile(outputFilePath, (err, info) => {

        if (err) throw err;
        // code to unlink file
         try{
          fs.unlinkSync(file.path)
         }
         catch(err){
           console.log(err)
         }
      })
return path.options.fileOut;
 }```
````

Comment: I have the same problem, if you figured out the solution, tell me.